# R : y[x] & x[y] when x,y vectors

Tags: r, vector

Silly question but for real i cant undestand what is happening here (Screenshot) ,especially in x[y]. In y[x] i undestand that he is getting the similar objects for x & y. But in x[y] he is getting objects that y is not having [image]

Comment: when a vector is put inside `[]` the said vector is treated as index number. `y[x]` returns 4 `NA` because `y` only has length of 7. Index number `8, 10, 12, 14`, thus, return NA

Answer (score 3, accepted):

x[y] is looking for the y'th index in x. Essentially it is looking for elements 1,2,3,4,5,6,7 in x, which correspond to the first 7 elements in x. Hence x[y] just returns the contents of x.

y[x] is looking for the x'th index in y - that is the 2nd, 4th, 6th, 8th etc up to 14th indexes. But since y is only 7 elements long, everything after that just returns NA, because there is no 8th index in y, and so on.

Answer (score 3):

### Data

```
x
[1]  2  4  6  8 10 12 14

y
[1] 1 2 3 4 5 6 7
```

### Explanation

The following returns the `yth` position of `x`, which is in this case, the first 7 elements of x (note that the first element of a vector in R has an index of `1` but not `0`)

```
x[y]
[1]  2  4  6  8 10 12 14
```

Similarly, this returns the `xth` position of `y`, which is the second, the 4th ... and the 14th element of `y`. However, since `y` only has 7 elements, it returns missing values (`NA`) after the seventh index.

```
y[x]
[1]  2  4  6 NA NA NA NA
```

Comment: I didnt realize that x or y inside is working like a index ... Thankss

Answer (score 3):

When you ask `x[y]` (respectively `y[x]`), you are actually asking the "yth" (resp. "xth") values of `x` (resp. `y`).

For instance :

```r
> x <- c(1, 4)
> y <- c(10, 20, 35, 70)
> y[x]
[1] 10 70
```

`y[x]` returns values of `y` at positions 1 and 4.

```r
> y[c(x, 10)]
[1] 10 70 NA
```

y[c(x, 10)] returns values of `y` at positions 1 and 4 and 10. The 10th value is missing, so it returns `NA`.